# Play store not supporting & not showing my app for Jelley Bean, KitKat versions

Tags: android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.4-kitkat, android, android-version

It was not showing on play store App on android mobiles, But this will available for all lower versions which below jellybean 
This is my app Link.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moblications.teamandy.wallframes
This is my Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.moblications.teamandy.wallframes"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="4.0" >

    <supports-screens 
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" 
    android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<compatible-screens>
     <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
     <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />

    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" /> 
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>

    <!--all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

</compatible-screens>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: It is showing up as compatible on a number of my KitKat devices - why do you even have the `<supports-screens>` and `<compatible-screens>` tags if you seem to be trying to support everything? They certainly aren't required...

Comment: Have you checked on Tab 2, Moto G & Nexus 5 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit:**

just found out that the android plugin doesn't know yet about `xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi`, but I found the workaround that ppl been using: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39622

just add:

```
<screen android:screenSize="..." android:screenDensity="480"/> <!-- xxhdpi -->
<screen android:screenSize="..." android:screenDensity="640"/> <!-- xxxhdpi -->
```

**original answer:**

I just tested and my Nexus 7 (2012) it works and my nexus 5 (2013) doesn't.

That points to one logical problem, there's no `android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"`, so you're filtering out any `xxhdpi` from your app.

But said that, I agree and +1 @ianhanniballake comment. Why bother with all those `compatible-screens` and `supports-screens`. If your app fits all, just remove those. Completely remove all of them and it will all be fine. Like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.moblications.teamandy.wallframes"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="4.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" 
    android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

</manifest>
```